# how to make splash screen in electron application?

Tags: electron

I am making an application with the help of angular 2 and electron.
I want to add a splash screen in this. I don't know how to do it. Please help me...

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  // create main browser window
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
      width: 1920,
      height: 1080,
      show: false // don't show the main window
  });
  // create a new `splash`-Window 
  splash = new BrowserWindow({width: 810, height: 610, transparent: true, frame: false, alwaysOnTop: true});
  splash.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/splash.html`);
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

  // if main window is ready to show, then destroy the splash window and show up the main window
  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    splash.destroy();
    mainWindow.show();
  });
});
```

I am also confused, where to put this splash.html file.

Comment: As seen from this code, the `splash.html` file should be in the root older of your project. Why not use `splash.close()`, rather than `destroy()`.

Comment: Logic seems to be fine. Is this question about `__dirname`'s meaning then?  see https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname . Also, using `path` module for resolving paths is the recommended way